# replace part of the string in C#

Tags: c#, substring

I have many strings which have **multiple spaces and one forward slash** like this:

```
string a="xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx aaa/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

or

```
string b="xxxx xxx xxxxxx bbbbb/xxxxxxx xxx";
```

or

```
string c="xx xx 12345/x xx"
```

What I need to do is to replace the substring "aaa" or "bbbbb" or "12345" (**Please note that the substrings are just examples, they can be anything**) with the new string I want.
The feature for the substring "aaa" or "bbbbb" or "12345" or anything is that the substring is right before the only one forward slash and right after the space in front of and closest to this slash.

How do I locate this substring so that I can replace it with the new substring I want? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for how to do this?

Comment: If you know where the space is, and you know where the slash is, the number between the two must be fixed unless the string changes.

Comment: If you want to learn a handy new skill (and some would say add another problem to the mix), have a look at [regular expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). They can do all this and a whole lot more. Otherwise you could write your own custom string parser which would be faster.  Depends what you want: a multi-tool that you'll use for the rest of your life or a solution to this specific problem :)

Comment: please use string.replace(char oldchar, char newchar)

Comment: You can literally type the title of your question into Google as is and I’m sure the first 20 results would provide an answer 

Comment: I definitely searched a lot, my question title can be quite common but I did not find similar substance as my question.@Charlie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Well, well well

## Take your universal method:

```
        public string Replacement(string input, string replacement)
        {
            string[] words = input.Split(' ');
            string result = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                if(words[i].Contains('/'))
                {
                    int barIndex = Reverse(words[i]).LastIndexOf('/') + 1;
                    int removeLenght = words[i].Substring(barIndex).Length;
                    words[i] = Reverse(words[i]);
                    words[i] = words[i].Remove(barIndex, removeLenght);
                    words[i] = words[i].Insert(barIndex, Reverse(replacement));
                    string ToReverse = words[i];
                    words[i] = Reverse(ToReverse);

                    break;
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                result += words[i] + " ";
            }

            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1);

            return result;
        }

        public string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
```

In reponse to >> I need a universal method to replace any stuff between the slash and the space closest to it

Answer (score 2):

although a proposed answer is selected. I still decide to answer my own question.

```
string substr=""//any string I want
string a=OldString.split('/');//split by '/'
string b=a[0].Substring(0,a[0].LastIndexOf(' '));//get the substring before the last space
string NewString= b+ substr + a[1];//the substring between the space and the '/' is now replaced by substr
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Expression could be something like this `"([^/]+)\\s(\\w+)/(.+)"`

`Regex.Replace (yourString, "([^/]+)\\s(\\w+)/(.+)", "$1 replacement/$3")`
[Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Anybody who knows how to get the double backslash to show up feel free to edit. Doesn't work so well trying to edit on phone.

Answer (score -1):

## Use string.Replace("", "");

```
string a="xxxxxx xxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxx aaa/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
string b="xxxx xxx xxxxxx bbbbb/xxxxxxx xxx";

string resultA = a.Replace("aaa", "Your replacement");
string resultB = b.Replace("bbbbb", "Your replacement");
```

Comment: this is not an ideal solution since op said there can be many a and b

Comment: @Agent_Orange his answer is correct.  He is showing "aaa" which is different from "a".   More specifically he should say "aaa/" but the point is still made.

Comment: hmm if thats true then this question to way very easy for any c# newbie

Comment: You tell me novice?
And, do you know that I have developed complete systems with connection to SQL, MySQL, Postgre, Crystal Reports and Report View?
And you still call me a novice?

Comment: Hi, that is not what I mean. I need a universal method to replace any stuff between the slash and the space closest to it.

Comment: sorry, the characteristic for the substring I want to replace is that it is between the space and the slash. (There is only one slash. The space is the one in front of and closest to the slash).

Comment: Hi, perhaps I did not express myself correctly before. Now I have edited my question.@Sam