# Issue when replacing strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Asking for best practice for doing the following, having this string in C#:

string sentence = "**I was** watching TV last night while she was reading a book and **you were** playing video games";

I'm trying to get it automatically replaced by something like:

"**you were** watching TV last night while she was reading a book and **I was** playing video games"

Problem here is I can't use

```
sentence.Replace("I was", "you were").Replace("you were", "I was")
```

because final sentence would look bad: 
"**I was** watching tv while she was reading a book and **I was** playing video games".

It might look simple but it is not as simple as it seems, can I get some advice please?

Comment: One of hte overloads of Replace allows you to defined the first & last Index it should cover. | You could also expand the replace strings to include "watching" and "playing" respeectively. Expanding the Search string to filler stuff is a common way to avoid fake positives. | However overall this belongs into the area of Language Science and Artificial Intelligence, not normal programming.

Comment: When replacing multiple item in a string and want to make sure your replacements are unique.  So the following will work : sentence.Replace("I was watching", "you were watching").Replace("you were playing", "I was playing")

Comment: This is a very interesting question. With code you introduce a third variable, but this is a string.

Comment: You could get the indices for each replacement location and then substring it.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164968/replace-part-of-the-string-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why not [capturing](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and just swapping: [`(?i)(\bI was\b)([^.;!?]*?)(\byou were\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/v02CJo/1) and replace with `$3$2$1`. Of course this would just work, if you wouldn't need to replace eg `you were...I was`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may leverage a MatchEvaluator as the replacement argument in `Regex.Replace`:

```
var sentence = "I was watching TV last night while she was reading a book and you were playing video games";
var result = Regex.Replace(sentence, @"\b(?:(I was)|you were)\b", m =>
    m.Groups[1].Success ? "you were" : "I was");
Console.WriteLine(result); 
// => you were watching TV last night while she was reading a book and I was playing video games
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/sUtvV4).

Here, `\b(?:(I was)|you were)\b` matches either `I was` (while capturing the match into Group 1) or `you were` as whole words (`\b` is a word boundary). If `m.Groups[1].Success` is *true*, the replacement is `you were`, else, it is `I was`.

Comment: awesome! a simple and elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to create two functions, one to replace the first occurence and the second to replace the last occurence :

```
public static string ReplaceFirstOccurrence (string Source, string Find, string Replace)
{
    int Place = Source.IndexOf(Find);
    string result = Source.Remove(Place, Find.Length).Insert(Place, Replace);
    return result;
}

public static string ReplaceLastOccurrence(string Source, string Find, string Replace)
{
    int Place = Source.LastIndexOf(Find);
    string result = Source.Remove(Place, Find.Length).Insert(Place, Replace);
    return result;
}
ReplaceFirstOccurrence(sentence, "I was", "you were");
ReplaceLastOccurrence(sentence, "you were", "I was");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very crude, would be slow for large strings, makes many memory allocations, but it's easy to explain and does the job.

```
var input = "I was watching TV last night while she was reading a book and you were playing video games";

var pairs = new [] { 
    (From: "I was", To: "you were"),
    (From: "you were", To:"I was")
    };

var s = input;
for(int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++) s = s.Replace(pairs[i].From, $"{{TOKEN{i}}}", ignoreCase: true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
for(int i = 0; i < pairs.Length; i++) s = s.Replace($"{{TOKEN{i}}}", pairs[i].To);

Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(s);
s = char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

### Output

```
I was watching TV last night while she was reading a book and you were playing video games
you were watching TV last night while she was reading a book and I was playing video games
You were watching TV last night while she was reading a book and I was playing video games
```